# No me despliega el menu de option value en PHP

Tags: php, html5

mi código ya lo probé y el error esta en este fragmento de código lo utilice en XAMP y lo carga de forma correcta pero en el hosting no lo hace mi lógica es que el servidor local acepta muchas veces errores sintácticos pero NO el hosting pero yo no alcanzo a ver si existe uno.

o si alguien ya le ha ocurrido?

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Producto</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="chosen-select" name="codigo" data-placeholder="-- Seleccionar Producto --" onchange="tampil_obat(this)" autocomplete="off" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
          $query_obat = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT codigo, nombre FROM estancias ORDER BY nombre ASC")
                                                or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
          while ($data_obat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_obat)) {
            echo"<option value=\"$data_obat[codigo]\"> $data_obat[codigo] | $data_obat[nombre] </option>";
          }
        ?>
      </select>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A mi me parece que esto ocurre debido a un problema de codificación y que sea muy probablemente a nivel de la base de datos. Los datos pueden estar viniendo con caracteres extraños que fastidian la creación de los `option`. Prueba a poner esto antes de ejecutar `mysqli_query`:  `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");` Revisa también que tanto en el HTML  como en el servidor tienes la codificación en `utf8`. [Puedes leer aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner los nombres de los indices entre comillas asi:

```
<div class="form-group">  
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Producto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select class="chosen-select" name="codigo" data-placeholder="-- Seleccionar Producto --" onchange="tampil_obat(this)" autocomplete="off" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                  $query_obat = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT codigo, nombre FROM estancias ORDER BY nombre ASC")
                                                        or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
                  while ($data_obat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_obat)) {
                    echo"<option value=\"$data_obat['codigo']\"> $data_obat['codigo'] | $data_obat['nombre'] </option>";
                  }
                ?>
              </select>
```